# How can values imported with ImportJSON be converted to numerical values?

Tags: arrays, json, google-sheets, array-formulas

I have discovered that values imported into Google Spreadsheets with ImportJSON are not numeric. They are text (obvious to me now) and cannot be summed.

How can they be converted? I have tried changing the Cell Format to numeric, but it does nothing.

The import is

```
=ImportJSON("https://api.liquid.com/executions?product_id=1&limit=10")
```

I wish to sum the 4th column Models Quantity, but the total is zero.

Comment: About `I have tried changing the Cell Format to numeric, but it does nothing.`, can you provide the detail of it? For example, I think that if you can provide the sample input and output values you expect, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Thank you for updating it. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation and goal, in order to sum the values of of `quantity` in the array of `models`, how about using a formula of `=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(ImportJSON("https://api.liquid.com/executions?product_id=1&limit=10","/models/quantity", "noInherit,noTruncate,noHeaders"))))`?

Answer (score 1):

Got it! RegEx to the rescue again.

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(D2:D11, "[^\d\.]+",)*1)
```

Then sum the resulting new column of numerical values.

Source: [How to Convert Currency Text to Number in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/convert-currency-text-to-number-in-google-sheets/)

Note: you have to change the fancy double quotes used in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTJSON("https://api.liquid.com/executions?product_id=1&limit=10")*1)
```

or if you see errors:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(
 IMPORTJSON("https://api.liquid.com/executions?product_id=1&limit=10")*1;     
 IMPORTJSON("https://api.liquid.com/executions?product_id=1&limit=10")))
```